# UITextField.textColor not called until UITextField gets focus

Tags: swift3, xcode8, swift4, xcode9

Could anybody explain please how/when .textColor is called for the UITextField?

XCode9, Swift 4

Consider the following code:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txt1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txt2: UITextField!

@IBAction func btnaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    txt1.textColor=UIColor.red
    txt1.backgroundColor=UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    txt2.textColor=UIColor.red
    txt2.backgroundColor=UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Everything is connected. When you run it and click on the button, only the backgroundColor gets set immediately. The .textColor remains the same. Only when the text field gets a focus, only then the .textColor changes.

Is this correct behaviour or a bug?

Thank you for comments.

I tried the same code in XCode 8, Swift 3 and it worked fine, so I believe it is probably a bug.

Comment: This is a weird behaviour. This could be because XCODE is still in beta version. (That is what is think)